# SQL, selecting entities that are not equal to what you find

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT HOTEL.ROOM
FROM HOTEL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKED
 ON BOOKED.ROOM = HOTEL.ROOM

 WHERE
    TO_DATE('&STARTDATE','DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN BOOKED.ARRIVALDATE 
 AND BOOKED.ARRIVALDATE + &NIGHTS
```

I need help, I need to search for rooms that are booked and return the ones that are available.
basically the user inputs a date into the query, and the number of nights he is staying. this is looked up in the BOOKED table, if the dates equal then that means the room is booked and it shouldn't select that one from the HOTEL.ROOM table.
EDIT: changed RIGHT OUTER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN, just realised it was selecting data from the wrong table

Comment: Your `FROM` clause references `DETAILS` and `BOOKED` tables. Where's the `HOTEL` table that is referenced elsewhere?

Comment: why do you have `ON BOOKED.ROOM = HOTEL.ROOM` and `WHERE BOOKED.ROOM != HOTEL.ROOM` ?

Comment: I thought the first one was simply to connect them, should they both be !=?

Comment: I think they're both the same thing, so if you use the 1st one to connect, then you should remove the 2nd one

Comment: Does BOOKED keep information of departure date? Is there a field DEPARTUREDATE or BOOKED.NIGHTS?

Answer (score 0):

Bookings in your date range:

```
SELECT *
FROM   BOOKED
WHERE  TO_DATE('&STARTDATE','DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN ARRIVALDATE AND ARRIVALDATE + &NIGHTS
```

Extend to find `HOTEL` rooms that are in this list i.e. booked:

```
SELECT ROOM
FROM   HOTEL
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   BOOKED
         WHERE  TO_DATE('&STARTDATE','DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN ARRIVALDATE AND ARRIVALDATE + &NIGHTS
         AND    ROOM = HOTEL.ROOM
       )
```

And those that are not in this list i.e. not booked:

```
SELECT ROOM
FROM   HOTEL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   BOOKED
         WHERE  TO_DATE('&STARTDATE','DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN ARRIVALDATE AND ARRIVALDATE + &NIGHTS
         AND    ROOM = HOTEL.ROOM
       )
```